# Application of Jensen's formula

Tags: complex-analysis

While studying for an upcoming complex analysis qualifying exam, I found the following problem in Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable (XI.1 exercise #2).

> Let $f$ be an entire function, $M(r)=\sup\{|f(re^{i\theta})|:0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\}$, $n(r)=$ the number of zeros of $f$ in $B(0;r)$ counted according to multiplicity. Suppose that $f(0)=1$ and show that $n(r)\log2\leq\log M(2r)$.

**Attempt:**

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ denote the zeros of $f$, repeated according to multiplicity. From [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) and the condition that $f(0)=1$, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\log\frac{r}{|a_k|}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f(re^{i\theta}|\,d\theta$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\log\frac{r}{|a_k|}\leq\log M(r).$$

And here is where I'm stuck. I could take exponentials of both sides, but I do not see any further progress being made toward the desired result. How would $\log2$ and $M(2r)$ come into the picture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
n(r) \log 2 \le \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\|a_k|\le r}}^n \log\frac{2r}{|a_k|}\le \sum_{k=0}^n \log\frac{2r}{|a_k|}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log|f(2re^{i\theta})|d\theta \leq \log{M(2r)}.
$$

Comment: Hah! Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use this version of Jensen's formula:
$$\int^R_0n(r)\,\frac{dr}{r}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0\log|f(Re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta-\log|f(0)|$$
Because $n(r)$ is non-decreasing,
$$n(r)\log{2}=n(r)\int^{2r}_r\frac{1}{t}\,dt\leq \int^{2r}_0n(t)\,\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0\log|f(2re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta\leq \log(M(2r))$$